# compare elements of a list one by one in python

Tags: python, for-loop, nested-loops

so I want to write a simple code to compare elements of a list one by one.

I defined a simple list with dictionary elements and try following:

```
x = [{'price': 66, 'distance': 1}, {'price': 63, 'distance': 2} \
    , {'price': 64, 'distance': 3}, {'price': 75, 'distance': 5}, \
     {'price': 75, 'distance': 10}, {'price': 60, 'distance': 10}, \
     {'price': 50, 'distance': 10}, {'price': 55, 'distance': 13},\
     {'price': 63, 'distance': 2}]

def nested_skyline():
    y = x
    for i in x:
        for j in x:
            if i != j:
                if i == {'price': 55, 'distance': 10} and j == {'price': 55, 'distance': 13}:
                    print('this')
                if (i['price'] == j['price']) and (i['distance'] < j['distance']):
                    y.remove(j)
                elif (i['price'] < j['price']) and (i['distance'] <= j['distance']):
                    y.remove(j)

    return y

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(nested_skyline())
```

but there is no stage with i = {'price': 55, 'distance': 10} and j = {'price': 55, 'distance': 13} and result of my code is:

```
[{'price': 66, 'distance': 1}, {'price': 63, 'distance': 2}, {'price': 60, 'distance': 10}, {'price': 50, 'distance': 10}, {'price': 55, 'distance': 13}, {'price': 63, 'distance': 2}]
```

I expected to see 'this' at the result and remove for example the dictionary {'price': 55, 'distance': 13}.

help me please.
thanks.

Comment: what is the desired result for the example you posted? I am not sure I understand what you want your code to do..

Comment: The list does not contain `{'price': 55, 'distance': 10}`

Comment: it should return a list with dictionaries with low price and distance. it likes that (a, b) < each (c, d) so it return (a,b). actually I want to compare all by all.

Comment: You should not remove items while you are in a loop of the iteration. You can record the items in a list, and then remove them.

Comment: yes @BlackBear but it contains :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you are aware that you shouldn't manipulate the list you're iterating through, but you missed one point:

```
y = x
```

This just makes `y` an alias of `x`, and any modification to `y` is also applied to `x`.

Try `y = x[:]` or `y = x.copy()` or `y = list(x)` so `y` becomes a copy of `x` and can be safely modified in the loop.

Comment: thanks @iBug. now it gives me the error list.remove(x): x not in list :(

Comment: @no-one You're likely removing an item twice. Try checking if it's in the list before removing it.

Comment: I correct that with replace y.remove(j0 with y = [d for d in y if d != j]. thanks and thanks iBug. :)